# what does THREE refer to in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

What is the THREE in three.js . For example, when we create a scene or any object we qualify the name like new THREE.Scene() or new THREE.WebGLRenderer() What does THREE refer to??

Comment: Look up "namespace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THREE refers to the THREE base object which contains all of the THREE stuff like geometry, materials, methods, and well every THREE thing really.

This is like calling your homie THREE who knows how to do all the THREE things, but only THREE things. You couldn't be like, "THREE.createWebpage()" because THREE doesn't know how to do that.

THREE is named in three.js which was first released by Mr. Doob.

If this still seems confusing I would recommend you look into what an object is in programming. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) is an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The base [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) of three.js - you can see the source [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js).

[image: THREE]

`THREE` stores all the properties and methods that make the library useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can just type "THREE" in Chrome console, and you will got what you want to know